# Trying to get all checkins open during day at specific times

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

Db structure looks somewhat like this.

```
id, transdate, opentime,            closetime
1   2015-11-02 2015-11-02 17:51:00  2015-11-02 18:51:17
2   2015-11-02 2015-11-02 17:58:00  2015-11-02 19:26:52
3   2015-11-02 2015-11-02 18:27:00  2015-11-02 20:13:00
4   2015-11-02 2015-11-02 19:33:00  2015-11-02 23:04:53
5   2015-11-02 2015-11-02 20:20:00  2015-11-02 22:23:30
6   2015-11-02 2015-11-02 20:41:00  2015-11-02 22:16:25
```

What I'm after is a result set something like this:

```
Hour, id
18    1
18    2
19    2
20    3
21    4
21    5
21    6
22    4
22    5
22    6
23    4
```

I've done some research and looks like a cte or something similar to make the hours for the day is needed.  But can't think how to join this to my table.

This is what I have:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SELECT @Date = '20151102 06:00:00'

;WITH Dates AS
(
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR,DATEADD(HOUR,1,@Date)) [Hour], 
  DATEADD(HOUR,1,@Date) [Date], 1 Num
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR,DATEADD(HOUR,-1,[Date])), 
  DATEADD(HOUR,1,[Date]), Num+1
FROM Dates
WHERE Num <= 24
)

Select 
d.hour, cih.checkinID 
from checkinheader as cih
join dates as d on d.hour= datepart(hh, cih.opentime)
where cih.transdate = '2015/11/02' and d.date between cih.opentime and cih.closetime
```

But I'm struggling with the join.  I basically want all checkins that are current for each hour, but not based on the opentime, or the close time, based on the ???? time the are open   does that make sense?  By doing the join on the opentime I don't get the result i'm after.  same with the close.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... solved... if anyone stumbles on this, this is what I did.

First up, there is a mistake in the CTE.  Also slight change to the join.  You can probably use this technique for finding users logged in a specific times, employees signed in etc.

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SELECT @Date = '20151102 06:00:00'

;WITH Dates AS
(
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR,DATEADD(HOUR,1,@Date)) [Hour], 
DATEADD(HOUR,1,@Date) [Date], 1 Num
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR,DATEADD(HOUR,1,[Date])), 
DATEADD(HOUR,1,[Date]), Num+1
FROM Dates
WHERE Num <= 24
)

Select 
d.hour, cih.checkinID 
from checkinheader as cih
join dates as d on 1=1
where cih.transdate = '2015/11/02' and d.date between cih.opentime andcih.closetime
```